# Widget not displaying label in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, widget, label

I want to display a window with a simple message in a pyqt5 app. To do that, I create a simple widget, a layout and a label. I add the label to the layout and assign the layout to the widget like so:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a widget to store information
load_widget = QWidget()
# Create a label with the message to display
load_label = QLabel()
# Set label text
load_label.setText('Data being imported, please wait...')
# Create a layout for the widget
load_layout = QVBoxLayout()
# Add label to the layout
load_layout.addWidget(load_label)
# Set layout for the widget
load_widget.setLayout(load_layout)
# Set window title
load_widget.setWindowTitle('Read SD')
# Show the widget
load_widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, the window is displayed along with its title but no label is shown as you can see in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: check my edit @eyllanesc

Comment: What is your OS? What version of PyQt5 do you have? Perhaps it is a bug of a specific version, try updating PyQt5.

Answer (score 0):

As @eyllanesc stated that is not an MRE because if one copy/pastes it and runs it they get:

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
```

I have expanded your code and formatted it properly and it works just fine

```
from sys import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui  import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# Outline a MainWindow Class using a QWidget
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

      # Set window title
        self.setWindowTitle('Read SD')

      # Create a label with the message to display
      # And and attach it to the MainWindow 
        self.lblLoad = QLabel()
      # Set label text
        self.lblLoad.setText('Data being imported, please wait...')
      # Create a layout for the widget
        VBox = QVBoxLayout()
      # Add label to the layout
        VBox.addWidget(self.lblLoad)
      # Add Stretch so Label stays at the top
        VBox.addStretch(1)
      # Set layout for the widget
        self.setLayout(VBox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Create Main Thread to Run Program In
    MainThred = QApplication([])
  # Create Main Window from Outlined Class
    MainGUI = MainWindow()
  # Show the Main Window
    MainGUI.show()
  # Launch the Main Thread
    sysExit(MainThred.exec_())
```

Comment: Is that an answer? improving the code format is not an answer

Comment: The error has nothing to do with QApplication, in another answer that was deleted the OP notes that it has created a QApplication. It is also evident that you have to have created it but the window shown in the image would not be displayed

Comment: The issue is, if you run some code just after calling the widget, the widget window is shown but the label does not appear.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes it is an answer -- as it actually works and displays the content of the QLabel within the QWidget MainWindow -- the reformatting was to fix the potential issues by putting into a more pythonic pyqt format rather than the non-functional MRE that was presented in the question.  I leave it to the querier to figure out what is wrong in their code -- I do not always give out fish but I do provide a fishing pole with bait

Comment: @najib the only code that should be run within __main__ is the code that is currently contained within __main__  if you need to run other code it should be launched from within MainWindow and driven by some Event such as a button click or a menu selection or etc...  --OR-- you need to call something else prior to calling MainWindow and then have that something else create and call the MainWindow -- of course if you were to provide an MRE of what you are trying to do that would greatly help us help you

Comment: @eyllanesc I never stated that the issue was QApplication all I did was display the error message one gets if one copies and pastes the current MRE that is not an MRE -- trying to help the OP understand why their MRE is not an MRE :)  as they seemingly misunderstood something about what an MRE should be

Comment: @DennisJensen You can point that out in the comments, just for that they serve: to point out to the OP how to improve your question, ask for clarifications, etc. And for me what you point out is not an answer, it is a comment. Anyway it is my opinion, if you take it great and if not, it is also great. :-)

Comment: @DennisJensen One thing is to help and another is to answered, a type of help is an answer but a comment can also be, well that's my opinion. I don't want to extend the discussion anymore, bye.